# Surrogate keys in NoSQL data model

Tags: cassandra, model, hbase, rdbms, accumulo

We are trying to migrate existing RDBMS to NOSQL database. Since we have concepts of surrogate keys in data warehousing, how do we handle those in terms of NOSQL databases?
What are the good practices in NOSQL database when it comes to migration of existing RDBMS to NOSQL database? 
We are looking for Accumulo, Cassandra or Hbase implementation.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I can tell some words about Cassandra and that would be related to any other key-value storage. It's schema modeling is query-based. So you need to think about your queries first, then create tables and keys according to the queries. 
 There would be data redundancy and denormalization, of course.
For instance, you may have a single table in the RDBMS containing both natural key and surrogate key. But if you're used to having your surrogate keys for searching, then for NOSQL it will be turned into 2 tables with `NaturalKey->Value` and `SurrogateKey->Value` relationships.
There is only one key for the NOSQL (though it can contain several columns) so there is no technical difference between the surrogate and natural keys, as they are both the "keys".
 The only thing you may find useful is that you need to UUID surrogate keys at Cassandra instead of counters (which look very similiar to autoincrement fields).
Surrogate keys are used in the data warehousing in a slightly different way: they are used for joining fact table with the dimension table, but the key-value DBs have no joins in terms of RDBMS.
You can find more information about Cassandra's data modeling and usage [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling), [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key) and [here](http://www.issart.com/blog/can-use-cassandra-big-data-world/).